# Can we upsert multiple tables (dynamic) using single stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, upsert

I am creating an activity to upsert data from source tables to target tables, I have multiple tables to be copied and the name of the table to be copied is sent as parameter to stored procedure.
Is there a way to dynamically create query to update/insert data in the table based on the tables(received as input through parameter) ?

Comment: *Yes*, you can use dynamic SQL to **safely** inject the table name **safely**. Just make sure you **safely** inject the tablename **safely**.

Comment: The answer to your question is Yes; any more than that would require a bit more detail in your question.

Comment: Is that the only parameter your procedure takes in? If that's the case, you might find a good starting point in my blog post entitled [T-SQL CRUD procedures auto-generator](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2020/02/06/t-sql-crud-procedures-auto-generator/).